# Как обыграть наследование при append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Приветствую народ.

Нужно показывать блок рядом с элементом по которому был сделан клик, сделано очень просто можете посмотреть:
http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2at/3/

```js
// При наведении на ссылку
$('.link_test').bind('click', function () {

    // Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    // Показываем блок
    //$(this).append( $(title) );
    $(title).slideDown(500);
});
```

```css
.link_test {
    position:relative;
    top:200px;
}
.subscribe {
    display:none;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:230px;
    bottom:-39px;
    z-index:100;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(15, 15, 15, .25);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:17px;
    text-shadow:none;
    -webkit-transition:bottom .3s ease;
    transition:bottom .3s ease;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.subscribe:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 80%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    width: 10px;
    height:19px;
    position: absolute;
    background:url("http://gtiradio.ru/img/arrow.png") no-repeat;
}
.subscribe .top {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.subscribe .top span {
}
.subscribe .top .close {
    left: 194px;
    top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.subscribe #sub_email {
    width:170px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.buttonm {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 185px;
    height: 30px;
    font: 16px/30px"Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.buttonm a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 1px 3px -1px;
    color:#fff;
}
.buttonm:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 1px 3px -1px;
    color:#fff;
}
.buttonm:hover {
    /*opacity: .9;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
}
.button-blue {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #56b4d0), color-stop(1, #1c94c4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
}
.buttonm2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font: 16px/30px"Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.buttonm2 a {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 1px 3px -1px;
    color:#fff;
}
.buttonm2:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    color:#fff;
}
.buttonm2:hover {
    /*opacity: .9;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
}
.button-blue2 {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #56b4d0), color-stop(1, #1c94c4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #56b4d0, #1c94c4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #115c7a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonm button-blue link_test" title="#sub">Подписаться</div>
<div id="sub" class="title subscribe">
    <div class="top"> <span class="heading-blue" style="font-size:18px !important;margin-left:-5px;">ПОДПИСАТЬСЯ</span>

        <div class="icons-item close-item close"></div>
    </div>
    <center>здесь вы можете подписаться на треклиты и новости радио-шоу</center>
    <input type="text" name="subscribe" id="sub_email" /> <span class="buttonm2 button-blue2">Оформить подписку</span>

</div>
```

с помощью append элемент открывается в элементе, но проблема в том что блок наследует прозрачность кнопки и некоторые ее свойства.

Как решить проблему подскажите и тыкните носом!

Comment: не вижу append в примере.

Comment: он там есть. 

Как вообще сделать чтобы показывался элемент рядом с ссылкой

Comment: так он у вас закомментирован. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TZ2at/5/ так надо ? только нехорошо использовать  атрибут предназначенный для другого. используйте data-title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> с помощью append элемент открывается в
> элементе, но проблема в том что блок
> наследует прозрачность кнопки и
> некоторые ее свойства.
>
> Как решить проблему подскажите и
> тыкните носом!

Отменить прозрачность потомков нельзя. 
Некоторые другие свойства можно отменить с помощью их переназначения для потомка.